# Android Studio 2.3 -Following version Android7.0 device APK installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio project can run debug and generate a apk.
But this .apk can only be installed success on Android7.0 device,and the same file can't install on Following version Android7.0 device.

When I made the following encountered this problem.

Android Studio upgrade to version 2.3,
gradle  upgrade to version 3.3

jre:1.8( no change )

Seems no error log ,in addition to the installation failed(where can i find this log?? e...)

How can I fix it ,thank you.

Comment: Please consider adding context and exact issue, a log would be welcome...

Comment: My project running debugging generate signed .apk is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when android studio updata just finished the upgrade modules properties the following

[image]

I made the following Settings,solve;

[image]